# How to prepare for INTERVIEW with PAIR PROGRAMMING (C#)

Tags: interview, visual-studio, pair-programming, nunit

I have a stage in an interview process where I am supposed to do pair programming, or at least they want to see me working in Visual Studio with an experienced developer.  This is a company promoting Scrum.

How should I behave?

How should I prepare?

I would think I should prepare for NUnit and perhaps MS-Test.  Are there other scenarios that are likely in a TDD/Agile environment?

(Perhaps something with Reshaper and MVC?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having done this from both sides of the table my guess would be that they want to see you program. Likely they will have some sort of simple problem you will have to solve.

The best prep you can do is to practice. Create a solution, add class libs, test projects and an app, web/wpf/wcf write some code covering the technologies they mention in the job app, Linq, PTL, REST, whatever, ensure you write unit tests and run them etc

A good question to ask is which version of Visual Studio they are using. You don't want to get tripped up because you are used to 2010 and they are on 2013 or vice versa. Similarly, do they use resharper? if you are used to that.

During the int, talk constantly through what you are typing, do the test first and build and run frequently so you pick up on any bugs/typos, ask the interviewer how they would do it "would you use dependency injection here?" and stuff as this indicates you know about the topic without having to do it/expressing an opinion about best practice

Comment: Would most such companies use re-sharper?  I just know its about .NET.  What I claim to know & have experience in besides pure code is Winforms and Webforms (which they are not likely to be using), But I also say I know abit about MVC, REST and WEB API.  So its a big chance it is just code, perhaps something they are working on, or perhaps a bug.

Comment: Yes many companies use re-sharper, but its more of a problem if they don't, and you are used to all its shortcuts. I would expect a simple problem such as FIzzBuzz. Its harder to prepare a problem than you might think